# Ext JS 4.1: Add click event listener to headerCheckbox

Tags: extjs, extjs4, onclicklistener, gridpanel, columnheader

I have a grid with selectable rows. You can find my code at [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/megacenupe/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

**How can I add a click event listener to the column header containing the checkbox?**

This code doesn't work:

```
this.columns[0].on('click', function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

Adding a listener to the checkbox is okay:

```
this.columns[0].textEl.on('click', function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

But I want the whole header, not only the checkbox, to listen for click events. :'(

How do I achieve this? Respectively, why does my code fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to add the event listener to headerCheckbox's element, not the component itself.

```
this.columns[0].el.on('click', function() {
    // Do stuff
});
```

See [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/sozocuxube/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Thx to @scebotari66 for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 2):

`this.columns[0]` seems to reference to your "1st column". Actually `this.columns.length` returns 2. Here are stored the references to the columns that you've declared in the `columns` config. To get a reference to the checkbox column you'll have to dig into `this.columnManager.columns`.

Also, the columns does not have a click event, so you set a click listener on their element.

This being said, here is the code:

```
listeners: {
    viewready: {
        fn: function () {
            var checkcolumnHeader = this.columnManager.columns[0];

            checkcolumnHeader.getEl().on('click', function () {
                console.log('clicked');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

And the working fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/262i

Comment: I assume your solution targets ExtJS 4.2 looking at your fiddle. In ExtJS 4.1 `this.columns[0]` does refer to the checkbox header cell. But you're right about adding the listener to the component's element, not the component itself. Thanks for the hint! :)